# Find the class of the generic object

Tags: java, type-erasure

Suppose I have the following class.

```
public class gen<T> {
   public gen(){
   }
   Class<T> class(){
      //something that figures out what T is.
   }
}
```

How can I implement the class() function without pass any additional information?

What I did is here, but I have to pass a object of T into the object gen.

```
public class gen<T> {
   public gen(){
   }
   Class<T> class(T var){
    return (Class<T>) var.getClass();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible to do this using a fair amount of reflection.  This link:

http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860

Has a pretty good discussion of how to do it.  It's tricky, evil, and hacky, but it can be done.

Comment: Good find! After reading it I guess it's much easier to stick with what I have now. haha

Answer (score 3):

You can't figure out the runtime value of `T`. This is due to [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: Wow, something like this can't be done. Java isn't as flexible as I thought it would be.

Comment: I guess the designers thought backwards compatibility was more important than the ability to do reflection like this. In practice it's rare to need to do this, right?

Answer (score 3):

No. The bytecodes for the compiled version of your class do not retain enough information to determine T, because of type erasure. What you've done with passing in an actual object of type T is about the best you can do.